# jquery dialog does not show CSS style on load in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery dialog which loads an external php page. All is working fine except in Internet Explorer (8) the css is switched on and then off again when the dialog is loaded.  This means the dialog is transparent! 
When I drag the dialog the style is applied again, and it keeps applied.

This the dialog load method.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
            $('a[name=eventform]').click(function(e) {
                //Cancel the link behavior
                e.preventDefault();

                $("#dialog").load(e.target.href).dialog({
                    title : 'Activity'
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
```

And this is the external page. All works fine in Firefox but the style is removed somehow when loading in Internet Explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $pgtitle ?></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar/css/popwin.css" />


    </head>
<body>
          ......
```

I tried to use the @import to get the stylesheet but this makes no difference.

The same issue appears on Internet Explorer 9 but there it happens sometimes (????).

Thanks,
Coen

Comment: Try changing `e.target.href` to `this.href`.

Comment: I believe dialog doesn't behave like an iframe. the css styling you should put inside your main page

Comment: @jSang, this makes no difference.

Comment: @Dreadedsemicolon the style is loaded fine, but it flickers on and quickly off again in IE. And then when dragged, the style is turned on again.

Comment: yes, but if it is not an iframe, this is not correct way to load css via ajax . so IE is right on this . you need to put your styling in the same page, or use iframe.  In fact it's better to use iframe for this one, because you want also to run js libraries. only if you tweak your page to work with your main page. dialog loads the result as html to be added to your main page.  then you get body inside body = mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
        $('a[name=eventform]').click(function(e) {
            //Cancel the link behavior
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#dialog").load(e.target.href, function(){
              $('#dialog').dialog({
                 title : 'Activity'
              })
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including the javascript at the bottom of the page, just before the end body tag. This prevent any modification to the DOM before the page is loaded.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
CONTENT
...
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```